# Flutter no actionbar found

Tags: android, flutter

error: failed processing manifest.

Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

> Android resource linking failed
> /Users/Raymond Tucker/AndroidStudioProjects/layzey/user-master 5/build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/release/AndroidManifest.xml:59: AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar (aka com.layzeyapp.user:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar) not found.

Android Manifest file

```
<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="user"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCoAzIWcx-pKh3GCWaWBdV2yV0QygSN0HY"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
             until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
             there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
             defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
            android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest file here?

Comment: try `flutter clean` in your terminal

Comment: if it doesn't work try to remove this line from you manifest under UCropActivity
`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Answer (score 0):

the issue is not with android it's cause some of your package I face the issue because of my google map package you can remove your last package you add, clean and run hope it will fix your issue.

Comment: Improve your response!
Could you give examples with a description of the codes, for your answer?
This practice will considerably improve this problem.